# Intalando o Visual Studio 2015 Community com SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, instalador

Instalei o *Visual Studio Community 2015* e queria conectá-lo com o SQL Server, mas pelo que entendi eu não preciso instalar o SQL Server, só preciso baixar o SQL Server Data Tools. É isso mesmo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Visual Studio pode instalar o SQL Server para você. Também pode instalar de forma separada se quiser alguma outra edição que não vem junto com o Visual Studio, que inclusive só pode ser usado para desenvolvimento.

O SQL Server Data Tools é totalmente opcional.

Comment: Vlw, eu não tinha o SQL Server instalado no notebook, então tentei instalar o SQL Server Data Tools e ele inclusive já pergunta se deseja ou não instalar o SQL Server. Fiz um teste no meu Desktop que já tem o SQL Server e na hora da instalação do SQL Server Data Tools o instalador nem pergunta se quero ou não instalar o SQL Server (provavelmente por já identifica-lo na máquina).